# Mysql Connector Mac Osx not working

Tags: mysql-connector, mysql-connector-c

I am trying to run the Mysql Hello World example in MAC OSX 10.12.6
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

2. I downloaded the C++ connector for mysql here for Mac OS https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
3. I have MAMP PRO installed as Mysql Server
4. When i compile the code and run it gives the following error

   Amans-MacBook-Pro:c++ khanakia$ g++ -o a -I/usr/local/include -I/Volumes/D/www/c++ -W -lmysqlcppconn a.cpp && ./a

   Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' » AS _message'...

   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type sql::SQLException

   Abort trap: 6

   Amans-MacBook-Pro:c++ khanakia$

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out here i found the solution and created a tutorial here

https://github.com/mrkhanakia/mysql-connector-cpp-macos

Regards,
[Aman Khanakia](https://www.linkedin.com/in/khanakia)